# Как написать конфиг для nginx, чтобы он на все пути отдавал один и тот же файл?

Tags: сервер, nginx

Есть некая директория `/nginx_root_dir`, в который лежит файл `index.html`. Как написать конфиг, чтобы на все адреса `domain.com`, `domain.com/app`, `domain.com/app/1` отдавался index.html?

**UPD:**
Вот сам файл. В папке dest лежит index.html. Почему не работает? Ошибка 404.

```
server {
  listen       127.0.0.1:80;
  server_name nodejs-server.com

  root /home/ivan/server/fron-end-empty/dest;


  log_not_found off;
  charset utf-8;

  location / {
    try_files index.html =404;
  }
}
```

Comment: error_page 404 = /index.html;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

на такую «заглушку» я перенаправляю при отсутствии сайта:

```
server {
  listen порт;
  server_name имя.сервера;
  error_page 404 /index.html;
  location / {
    root   /каталог;
    index  index.html;
}
```

}

в `/каталог` лежит единственный файл — `/каталог/index.html` с нужным сообщением.

Answer (score 2):

Так, например:

```
server {
  listen       127.0.0.1:80;
  server_name nodejs-server.com

  log_not_found off;
  charset utf-8;

  location / {
    alias /home/ivan/server/fron-end-empty/dest/index.html;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
location / {
  try_files /index.html =404;
}
```

Comment: сделал, как Вы сказали и не работает. Почему?

Comment: @shatal магия! Попробуйте слеш в начало добавить...

Comment: не помогает....